# Recovery Call Back - Retain Header Information

Tags: spring-integration

Could you please let us know, how [if possible] to retain the headers (such as reply channel) when all the retry attempts are exhausted and we have provided a recovery callback channel.

Currently, the recovery call back channel does not appear to retain any header information that are in place before the exception happened.

Simply put, How to make/configure the Throwable (error message) to retain header information during recovery call back (after retry exhaustion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be much more precise with your language, and show your configuration. I don't know what you mean by "recovery callback channel". If you mean the error channel configured into a `ErrorMessageSendingRecoverer` in a `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice`, the message is an `ErrorMessage` with payload `MessagingException`.

The `MessagingException` has two properties `cause` and `failedMessage`.

You can find the original headers on the `failedMessage`.

If you mean something else, please explain by editing your question (and add a comment here so I get a notification).